# Почему не срабатывает сеттер и неверно работает биндинг кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть вот такой код:

```
<Window x:Class="CWServer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWServer"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Input" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=Processing, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>    
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Click="btChangeState_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Stop"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Text="Bottom:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BottomString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Grid.Column="3" 
                 Grid.Row="3"
                 Style="{StaticResource Input}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Top:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TopString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Grid.Column="3"
                 Grid.Row="5"
                 Style="{StaticResource Input}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Step:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StepString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Grid.Column="3" 
                 Grid.Row="7"
                 Style="{StaticResource Input}"/>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="9">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ProgressBar Name="pbSolvingProgress"/>

            <Label Name="tbTimeLeft" 
                   Content="{Binding Path=TimeLost, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
                   ToolTip="Estimated time remaining to solve the task." 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="Result:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11"/>

        <TextBox Name="tbResult" Text="{Binding Path=ResultValue, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11"/>

        <Button Content="Solve"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=btSolve_IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                Grid.Row="13" 
                Click="btSolve_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

и

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using PropertyChanged;
using CWServer.Contracts;

namespace CWServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
        public bool Processing { get; private set; }
        public bool btSolve_IsEnabled { get { return IsRunning && !Processing && !HasValidationErrors; } }    
        public JobService Instance { get; } = new JobService();
        public int TimeLost { get; private set; } = 0;
        public double? ResultValue { get; private set; } = null;

        public string BottomString
        {
            get { return _BottomString; }
            set
            {
                if (!double.TryParse(value, out BottomValue))
                {
                    BottomIsValid = false;
                    throw new FormatException();
                }

                if (BottomValue < 0 || BottomValue >= TopValue)
                {
                    BottomIsValid = false;
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                BottomIsValid = true;
                _BottomString = value;
            }
        }

        public string TopString
        {
            get { return _TopString; }
            set
            {
                if (!double.TryParse(value, out TopValue))
                {
                    TopIsValid = false;
                    throw new FormatException();
                }

                if (TopValue < 0 || TopValue <= BottomValue)
                {
                    TopIsValid = false;
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                TopIsValid = true;
                _TopString = value;
            }
        }

        public string StepString
        {
            get { return _StepString; }
            set
            {
                if (!double.TryParse(value, out StepValue))
                {
                    StepIsValid = false;
                    throw new FormatException();
                }

                if (StepValue <= 0 || StepValue > (TopValue - BottomValue))
                {
                    StepIsValid = false;
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                StepIsValid = true;
                _StepString = value;
            }
        }

        private double BottomValue = 0.0;
        private double TopValue = 200.0;
        private double StepValue = 0.000001;
        private bool HasValidationErrors { get { return !BottomIsValid || !TopIsValid || !StepIsValid; } }
        private bool BottomIsValid = true;
        private bool TopIsValid = true;
        private bool StepIsValid = true;
        private string _BottomString;
        private string _TopString;
        private string _StepString;        

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _BottomString = BottomValue.ToString("0.#######");
            _TopString = TopValue.ToString("0.#######");
            _StepString = StepValue.ToString("0.#######");
        }

        private void btChangeState_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsRunning = !IsRunning;
            Processing = false;
        }

        private void btSolve_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Processing = !Processing;
        }
    }
}
```

Есть две проблемы которые скорее всего связаны. Во первых если я в одном из полей ввода ввожу невалидные данные, а потом просто удаляю их то сеттер у свойства обозначающего их строковое представление (BottomString / TopString / StepString) не срабатывает. Например я ввожу "123q" - сеттер срабатывает и выкидывает исключение, но если я просто удалю символ 'q' с конца строки backscape-ом - то сеттер не срабатывает почему то и у меня все из за этого ломается... И еще одна проблема в том что кнопка Solve не реагирует на ошибки, хотя должна становиться неактивной засчет биндинга.

P.S. Если что там я использую Fody.PropertyChanged заместо INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38300/discussion-on-question-by-dark-byte-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По материалам длинного обсуждения в комментариях:

1. Проблема номер 1 пропадает, если вместо autowired-`INotifyPropertyChanged` при помощи библиотеки Fody использовать реализацию INPC вручную. Выглядит как баг в Fody.
2. Проблема номер 2 заключается в том, что `btSolve_IsEnabled` — вычисляемое свойство с одним лишь сеттером. Для них при изменении зависимости, понятно, `PropertyChanged` не вызывается. Поэтому его изменения не заметны снаружи.

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема 1**

Происходит из-за того, что по умолчанию Fody вписывает проверку на равенство нового значения со старым **в начало** сеттера. И получается вот такой код

```
public string BottomString
{
  get
  {
    return this._BottomString;
  }
  set
  {
    if (string.Equals(this._BottomString, value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
      return;

    if (!double.TryParse(value, out this.BottomValue))
    {
      this.BottomIsValid = false;
      throw new FormatException();
    }
    if (this.BottomValue < 0.0 || this.BottomValue >= this.TopValue)
    {
      this.BottomIsValid = false;
      throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    this.BottomIsValid = true;
    this._BottomString = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("BottomString");
  }
}
```

Получается следующая ситуация:

- 123 вызывает _BottomString = value;
- 123q бросает исключения и до _BottomString = value; не доходит и
  _BottomString остается равно 123
- После нажатия бэкспейса  новое значение 123 равно старому значению _BottomString и потому происходит выход из сеттера до места, где можно поставить точку останова и кажется, что сеттер не срабатывает

Аттрибут DoNotCheckEquality  решает эту проблему

**Проблема 2**

События OnPropertyChanged (а также те которые AlsoNotifyFor/DependsOn) вписываются в **конце** и когда летит исключение, то до OnPropertyChanged просто не доходит

Тут придется делать ручной вызов OnPropertyChanged при броске исключения или еще как, чтобы сообщить, что статус кнопки изменился.

Или попросить автора Fody добавить поддержку аттрибутов которые вызовут OnPropertyChanged в finally, а именно чтобы по другому была реализация AlsoNotifyFor/DependsOn

Comment: Окей, первая часть кажется мне багом на стороне Fody. Пропускать тело сеттера в случае, если новое значение совпадает со значением одного из полей, неверно. Fody ошибочно посчитал, что backing field у данного свойство одно — `_BottomString`, в то время как на самом деле сеттер устанавливает ещё и `BottomIsValid`.

Comment: Вторая часть тоже мне кажется нарушением: если уж Fody считает свойство зависимым, оно _должно_ при изменении его значения запускать event. То, что оно этого не может в случае исключения — проблема Fody, вручную проблема решается.

Comment: @VladD а) Ваша имплементация Set<T> тоже содержит первым делом компарер )). Это классическая имплементация INPC свойства. Fody просто пишет его за вас полностью или частично. б) Fody не интересует _BottomString. Он просто дописал упущенный OnPropertyChanged("BottomString") а в сеттере BottomIsValid он тоже дописал OnPropertyChanged("BottomIsValid") - где как бы и должно оно быть.

Comment: @VladD в методе не указано, что нужно уведомить про изменение "btSolve_IsEnabled". Тут автор вопроса сам забыл сделать это. Автор должен был использовать try..finally. Для этого Fody предоставляет аттрибуты для автогенерации OnPropertyChanged(связанное свойство),  но оно не учитывает исключения увы. Конечно было бы удобно, чтобы можно было разрулить аттрибутами (и я создал тикет на гитхабе), но думаю это не так просто сделать будет, ведь важно сберечь возможность дебага, которая щас работает внутри сеттеров, если там есть свой код.

Comment: Моя имплементация отлаживаема. Если есть проблема, то её можно увидеть просто в отладчике, а не посвятив несколько дней поискам по форумам и копанию в IL-коде вне отладчика. Это существенный плюс.

Comment: Моя имплементация содержит `Set`, который возвращает `bool`. Типичный паттерн использования: `if (Set(ref field, value)) { ... }`. И если мне реально нужно проверить несколько полей, это легко делается вручную, программист **видит** логику, может её оттрассировать, и понимает, куда и что нужно вставить. Для Fody нужно знание о том, где и что он вставляет, в каких случаях это работает, а в каких нет. Причём ошибочные случаи не вызывают предупреждения или ошибку компиляции. Это и приводит к плохим результатам.

Comment: @VladD Нужно лишь знание, что делает Fody - он делает *классическую* имплементацию свойства (проверка, присвоение, нотификация). *Он не творит магию*. Редки случаи когда value нужно сверить на равенство еще с чем то (даже кейсов не было).Set или Fody - все равно придется делать пользовательским кодом, который прекрасно срабатывает на точках останова. В случае автора за минуту можно глянуть что там Fody нагенерил, запомнить что Fody делает классическую имплементацию не попадаться на эти грабли. Автор и без Fody кидает исключения до присвоения и не указывает что еще надо бы нотифицировать

Comment: В том-то и дело, что подробности того, как делает Fody скрыты, и их надо помнить. А вызов метода `Set` легко трассируется. Поэтому Fody — это магия (причём не всегда работающая), а `Set` — простая и понятная любому штука. Впрочем, я уже об этом говорил.

Comment: И непонятно, как диагностировать неприход в ожидаемую точку останова.

Comment: @VladD ну я же диагностировал. Запустил DotPeek, увидел, что Fody вставил компарер в начале и OnPropertyChanged в конце и сразу понял проблему автора. Fody не сделал магии, а всего - лишь дописал до классической имплементации. Для случая автора сравнение из классики лишнее, что можно убрать, чтобы Fody не вставлял. А можно сделать чтобы вообще не лез к этому свойству. И нет никаких подробностей - Fody не ищет зависимости, не пытается переписать сеттер, а просто пишет типичный boilerpate для INPC свойств. У автора нестандартный случай когда бэкенд другого типа и он сам накосячил

Comment: Ну, снова-таки, я бы не рекомендовал библиотеку, при использовании которой для отлова ошибок необходим декомпилятор. И **особенно** не рекомендовал бы новичкам.

Comment: Ну и снова-таки тупая вставка кода в начале и в конце хороша для простых случаев. А то, что случай не простой, Fody стоило бы сдетектировать и выдать ошибку. Иначе и получается молчаливый вред. Сможете найти такого же «качества» фичу в BCL?

Comment: @VladD 1) новичок, который в 1000й раз напишет одну и ту же реализацию INPC свойства перестает быть новичком. 2) Ну да. Тупая вставка кода. Тупое дописывание одной и той же лапши за пользователя. Та же T4 просто автогенерация кода, без магии. Те же сниппеты для генерации INPC свойства. Fody и берут, чтобы он дописывал то, что "новичок" устал писать руками. От него этого и ожидают. Получается то, что и руками. Банальная автогенерация кода (просто на уровне IL, что делает код чище, а t4 и сниппеты на уровне кода), без магии.

Comment: Ну, я уже говорил о том, что считаю отсутствие отладки критическим недостатком. А тупая вставка кода могла бы быть не тупой. Основной принцип хорошего проектирования всегда был «не уверен — не ломай». Fody ведь не было уверено, что добавка раннего выхода не сломает логику юзера? Я вообще считаю, что добавлять ранний выход для чего угодно, кроме автосгенерированного сеттера — грубая ошибка.

Comment: @VladD а где там нет отладки? для автосвойства она не нужна по определению. Если же сеттер свой, то отладчик не видит только то, что добавил Fody - сравнение со старым значением и вызов OnPropertyChanged. Весь остальной код прекрасно проходится отладчиком, в том числе и руками вписанный OnPropertyChanged. И, наконец, можно попросту попросить Fody вообще не лезть в свойство частично или полностью. "могла бы быть не тупой"...Fody это сниппет на уровне IL(так кода меньше) и он не запрещает не использовать его в нужном месте.