# C# wpf MVVM - правильное проектирование

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Появились недопонимания в проектировании приложения используя MVVM паттерн.
Имеется POCO класс Person который необходимо заполнить данными из текстовых полей, чтобы можно было в дальнейшем серелизовать объект и отправить на сервер:

```
class Person
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _lastName;
        private string _patronymic;

        private PersonLocation _registration;



        public string PersonName
        {
            get {return this._name;}
            set { this._name = value; }
        }

        ....
    }
```

Класс PersonLocation хранит в себе данные место проживания лица:

```
class PersonLocation
    {


        private Country _country;
        private Region _region;
        private District _district;
        private City _city;
        private Quarter _quarter;
        private string _cityAdditional;
        private string _street;
        private string _home;
        private string _flat;


        public Country Country
        {
            get{    return this._country;   }
            set{    this._country = value;  }

        }

        public Region Region
        {
            get { return this._region; }
            set { this._region = value; }
        }

        public District District
        {
            get { return this._district; }
            set { this._district = value; }
        }

        public City City
        {
            get { return this._city; }
            set { this._city = value; }
        }

        public Quarter Quarter
        {
            get { return this._quarter; }
            set { this._quarter = value; }
        }

        public string CountryName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }
```

Класс MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : Notify
{

   private Person person;
   private PersonLocation  location = new PersonLocation();

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        this.person = new Person();
        this.location = new PersonLocation();


    }

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return this.person; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Собственно, сама разметка:

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock>Имя:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox  Height="27" ></TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock>Фамилия:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox  Height="27" ></TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock>Отчество:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox  Height="27" ></TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
```

Как привязать все текстовые поля и списки к объекту Person? Будет ли правильно написать:

```
<TextBox  Height="27" Text="Binding CurrentPerson.PersonName"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, объект `Person` не является нормальным VM-объектом, в частности, не реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`. (А к `_registration`, судя по всему, вовсе нет доступа.) Поэтому пытаться привязываться к нему неправильно: в некоторых простейших сценариях это всё ещё будет работать, но в общем случае — нет.

Заведите VM-объект, в котором будут нужные свойства. В нужный момент, когда таблица заполнена, скопируйте все свойства в POCO-объект в методе вашей VM (например, вы можете выставить в VM команду и привязать её к кнопке OK).

Comment: Кстати удобно для ViewModel удобно использовать  PropertyChanged.Fody https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/304678/

Comment: @Serginio: С Fody не так всё гладко, тут был вопрос с проблемой: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511958/10105

Comment: Спасибо . Кстати на эту тему есть статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/312048/  Fody кстати тоже генерирует при компиляции нужный код.

Comment: @Serginio: Ага, спасибо, почитаю.