# Есть ли способ делать не такие громозкие события?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Реализация в модели (в паттерне MVVM), каждой публичной переменной так:

```
    private bool _isGraphSet;
    public bool isGraphSet {
        get { return _isGraphSet; }
        private set { _isGraphSet = value; OnPropertyChanged("isGraphSet"); }
    }
```

Совсем не радует. Есть ли способы сделать все более человечески?

Comment: Для таких простых свойств можно использовать [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться такой заготовкой.

Для начала, вы определяете базовый класс для ваших VM:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                          [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Затем, в ваших VM-классах вы пишете вот так:

```
class GraphVM : VM
{
    private bool _isGraphSet;
    public bool isGraphSet {
        get { return _isGraphSet; }
        private set { Set(ref _isGraphSet, value); }
    }
}
```

---

К IL-weaver'ам наподобие Fody у меня неоднозначное отношение.

С одной стороны, AOP — это как бы хорошо и правильно.

С другой стороны, с Fody [возникают баги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511438/10105). Хуже того, поскольку кодогенерация происходит за сценой, вряд ли получится влёгкую отлаживать связанные с этим проблемы, если что-то пошло не так: у вас ведь нету исходного кода!

Поэтому я бы подождал, пока в C# не будет реализовано replace/original ([вот](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5292) и [вот](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16160)), чтобы иметь над кодогенерацией полный контроль с возможностью пошаговой отладки.

Comment: Все зависит от стиля разработки. Не все любят кидать исключения в сеттерах, а для зависимых полей есть специальные аттрибуты AlsoNotifyFor/DependsOn - при таком подходе проблем с Fody не имел, а есть еще DoNotCheckEquality. Единственное неудобство Fody - врапперы над моделями все равно вручную приходится писать.

Comment: @vitidev: Образец проблемы есть по ссылке. То, что вы не наткнулись на баг — слава богу, а вот другому участнику не так повезло.

Comment: Но там нет бага. Fody просто вписывает проверку на равенство значения в начало метода. 123 -> значение присвоено. 123q- вылетело исключение и _BottomString = value; не сработало и значение осталось 123. Удаляем бэкспейсом q и новое значение совпадает со старым и из сеттера выходит до выполнения пользовательского кода (где и можно поставить точку останова). Установка DoNotCheckEquality не вписывает эту проверку и сеттер срабатывает всегда

Comment: @vitidev: По-моему, это баг, сеттер должен вызываться. А то, что Fody этого молча не смогло, а требует какого-то шаманства с атрибутами, вдвойне проблематично. Именно поэтому я и не советую магию типа Fody: отладить её малореально.

Comment: Вы не поняли. сеттер вызывается всегда. детально я описал проблему по вашей ссылке. Это просто особенность реализации, что Fody впихивает свой код в начале и конце. Баг ли это - вопрос спорный. Я бы сказал, что нужно попросить автора фоди добавить аттрибут для случаев с throw Exception

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, если есть чужой код, но необходимо предполагать, что этот код бросит исключение. Я посмотрю подробнее позже (и отпишусь в комментах к тому вопросу).

Comment: Ну, как бы не дело библиотеки требовать от пользователя не бросать исключения. Исключения в сеттере при невалидных данных — правильный дизайн.

Comment: Fody ничего не требует. Он просто генерит боилерплейт код. Точно так же в случае исключений проггер не сможет использовать ваш Set<T>(ref T field, а полностью реализовывать сырой метод. Нет никакой разницы.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне понравился Fody. Вопрос немного не по теме, V реагирует на изменение VM и обновляет данные, но как правильно подписать VM на изменение в M? У меня приходят данные по USB HID и реализовано это в M как событие, как протащить приход данных от M до V?

Comment: @Fangog: Ну в общем я предупредил вас насчёт Fody, так что будьте осторожны на этом пути.

Comment: @Fangog: Как угодно, между M и VM нету правильного или неправильного методов. VM пусть подписывается на изменения M, и обновляет VM-классы. А уж View следит за VM через Binding.

Comment: @Fangog для подписки VM на обновления M нужно чтобы M реализовывала тоже INPC, а дальше либо руками либо в MVVM фреймворках есть всякие PropertyObserver классы либо а AssociateProperty, внутри которых идет подписка на INPC

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то написал вот такой велосипед с использованием [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), который перехватывает вызов сеттера свойств в моделях представления и автоматически дергает `PropertyChanged`:

```
// Базовый класс для всех VM
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var evt = PropertyChanged;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Создание прокси к VM с помощью Castle.DynamicProxy
    public static T Create<T>() where T : ViewModelBase
    {
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        return generator.CreateClassProxy<T>(new PropertyChangedInterceptor());
    }
}

// Тестовая VM. Ручного кода, как видите, совсем нет
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public virtual string TestProperty { get; set; }
}

// Перехватчик обращений к свойствам
public class PropertyChangedInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var proxy = invocation.Proxy as ViewModelBase;
        if (proxy != null && IsSetter(invocation.Method)) {
            // если происходит вызов сеттера свойства в VM
            // то получаем текущее значение свойства
            // и, если оно изменилось, вызываем PropertyChanged
            PropertyInfo property = GetPropertyBySetter(invocation.Method);
            object currentValue = property.GetValue(proxy, null);
            object newValue = invocation.Arguments[0];
            if (IsModified(currentValue, newValue)) {
                invocation.Proceed();
                proxy.RaisePropertyChanged(property.Name);
            }
        } else {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }

    public static bool IsModified(object currentValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(currentValue, null))
            return !ReferenceEquals(newValue, null);

        return !currentValue.Equals(newValue);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyBySetter(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        return mi.DeclaringType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetSetMethod() == mi);
    }

    public static bool IsSetter(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        return mi.DeclaringType.GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetSetMethod() == mi);
    }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что теперь в моделях представления вообще нет лишнего кода, мне самому до сих пор кое-что не нравится. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь покритикует это решение.

- Нельзя создать модели представления через конструктор, только через фабричный метод. Создание VM придется явно прописывать в code behind (`DataContext = ViewModelBase.Create<TestViewModel>()`). При этом конструктор сделать приватным нельзя (иначе возникнет исключение в `ProxyGenerator`).
- Вызов `property.GetValue(proxy, null)` инициирует рекурсивный вызов метода `Intercept` (вроде бы обратиться напрямую к backing field автосвойства через рефлексию без хаков нельзя).
- `RaisePropertyChanged` торчит наружу.
- Проблемы с производительностью.