# Выбор viewmodel при смене tabitem в tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

Здравствуйте!
В приложении используется одна главная форма, на которой имеется общий список объектов, и TabControl, во вкладках которого над этими объектами можно выполнять некоторые действия. Количество TabItems заранее известно, конечно и уникально для каждого действия. Для этих действий я сделал UserControl. Для каждого свой, уникальный.

Вопрос: как передать в ViewModel каждого UserConrtol идентификатор выбранного объекта, и общие команды (как "*Сохранить*", *"Стереть*")? Или наоборот, как главного ViewModel понять, что было переключение TabItem, и соответственно работать с ним?

Была мысль воспользоваться примером AvalonDock для MVVM. Но не смог осилить роль TemplateSelector и ContentTemplate (ItemTemplate). И как это связать с ViewModels?

Фрагмент разметки

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                        Header="Объекты" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TabControl Grid.Column="1" >
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <Views:ViewModel1 />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2"><Views:ViewModel2 /></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3"><Views:ViewModel3 /></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Желательно что бы вы указали язык, и привели пример того что и как сделали, и что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Особых проблем не видно.

Для обработки Save и т. п. вам имеет смысл использовать `CompositeCommand`, как указано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105).

А для того, чтобы узнать в VM, какой из табов активен, используйте привязку к `SelectedItem`.

Да, и в MVVM категорически запрещено создавать VM из View. Нужно делать как-то так:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentAction}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">
                <TextBlock Text="Заголовок таба View Model 1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel2}">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab2"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">
                        <Views:ViewModel1Control />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel2}">
                        <Views:ViewModel2Control />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

То, что количество табов заранее известно, не играет никакой роли. Не пытайтесь сэкономить, используя этот факт.

---

Написал небольшой пример использования.

Сначала VM. Базовый VM-класс можно взять отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628276/10105.

Пишем. Данные:

```
class DataVM : VM
{
    public DataVM(string data) => this.data = data;
    string data;
    public string Data { get => data; set => Set(ref data, value); }
}
```

Действие. Сделаем превьюшку результата. Получается абстрактный класс:

```
abstract class ActionVM : VM
{
    DataVM target;
    public DataVM Target
    {
        get => target;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref target, value))
                Preview = target == null ? null : new DataVM(Transform(target.Data));
        }
    }

    DataVM preview;
    public DataVM Preview
    {
        get => preview;
        set => Set(ref preview, value);
    }

    protected abstract string Transform(string target);
    public ICommand Apply { get; }

    public ActionVM(Action<DataVM> writeBack)
    {
        Apply = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            Target = Preview;
            writeBack(Target);
        });
    }
}
```

И две конкретных имплементации:

```
class AddStringVM : ActionVM
{
    public string Suffix { get; }
    public AddStringVM(string suffix, Action<DataVM> writeBack) : base(writeBack) =>
        Suffix = suffix;
    protected override string Transform(string target) => target + Suffix;
}

class RemoveStringVM : ActionVM
{
    public string StringToRemove { get; }
    public RemoveStringVM(string stringToRemove, Action<DataVM> writeBack) :
        base(writeBack) => StringToRemove = stringToRemove;
    protected override string Transform(string target) => target.Replace(StringToRemove, "");
}
```

Ну и главная VM:

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataVM> Data { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<DataVM>();
    public ObservableCollection<ActionVM> Actions { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ActionVM>();

    ActionVM currentAction;
    public ActionVM CurrentAction
    {
        get => currentAction;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref currentAction, value))
                currentAction.Target = CurrentData;
        }
    }

    DataVM currentData;
    public DataVM CurrentData
    {
        get => currentData;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref currentData, value) && currentAction != null)
                currentAction.Target = CurrentData;
        }
    }

    void WriteBack(DataVM data)
    {
        var index = Data.IndexOf(currentData);
        Data.RemoveAt(index);
        Data.Insert(index, data);
        CurrentData = data;
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        // создаём операции
        Actions.Add(new AddStringVM(" world", WriteBack));
        Actions.Add(new AddStringVM(" silly", WriteBack));
        Actions.Add(new RemoveStringVM(" world", WriteBack));

        // читаем данные из базы в фоновом потоке
        Data.Add(new DataVM("Hello world"));
        Data.Add(new DataVM("Goodbye world"));
    }
}
```

И XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentData}" DisplayMemberPath="Data"/>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentAction}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:AddStringVM}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Suffix, StringFormat='Дописать {0}'}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:RemoveStringVM}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringToRemove, StringFormat='Убрать {0}'}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ActionVM}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Target.Data, StringFormat='До: {0}'}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Preview.Data, StringFormat='После: {0}'}"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Apply}" Content="Применить"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за ссылку на описание MVVM, давно читал, хотел себе сохранить, но из-за ошибки браузера потерял эту страницу. Касательно решения моего вопроса: Спасибо за пример разметки, сейчас попробую применить к своему решению. Остался вопрос как передать выбранный в DataGrid объект в выбранный (активный) ViewModel?

Comment: Ещё нашел [решение](https://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mvvm-using-contenttemplateselector-in-tab-control-view/), пытаюсь в нем разобраться

Comment: Ещё появился вопрос о MVVM: если модель живет своей жизнью, и сама решает вопросы о получении данных, означает ли это, что модель может содержать коллекцию объектов (данных), которые она считывает из БД (или любого другого места) и предоставляет эту коллекцию в VM?

Comment: @АртемийСоболев: Ну, а где у вас находится `DataGrid`? Снаружи? И в какой момент нужно передавать? В любом случае, связыванием VM должна заниматься корневая VM, которая их содержит. (Ну или не корневая, а более близкая к корню.)

Comment: @АртемийСоболев: Да, база данных — типичый модельный объект.

Comment: DataGrid живет на главной форме, на которой находится и TabControl. Передавать нужно при выборе пользователем элемента в DataGrid. В указанном вами примере какого типа должны быть Actions и CurrentAction? Пока пример у меня не заработал. Наверно всё-таки нужен TemplateSelector? Только как его прикрутить? Пробую решение, указанное по ссылке, приведенной мною ранее.

Comment: @VladD, А почему  категорически запрещено создавать VM из View?

Comment: @АртемийСоболев: `Actions` — это коллекция из VM-объектов `ViewModel1`, `ViewModel2` и. т. д., находится по идее в главной VM. `CurrentAction` — тоже свойство в главной VM, такого типа, чтобы туда можно было записать и `ViewModel1`, и `ViewModel2`. `TemplateSelector` не нужен.

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич: Логическая причина: View — штука подчинённая, не имеет права управлять приложением. Техническая причина: VM нужно связываться между собой, связать между собой VM, если они создаются в XAML'е, очень сложно (т. к. нельзя передать одну VM в качестве параметра в конструктор другой), приходится городить костыли.

Comment: @VladD, подскажите пожалуйста а как тогда присоединить VM к view, имея в главной VM список (List) с уже готовыми VM для UserControl, которые в свою очередь будут отображаться на tabitem? Ведь не из CodeBehind класса их биндить? Да и там их как-то получить надо из главной VM

Comment: @АртемийСоболев: Написал пример, сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Пока у меня не получается привязать ViewModel  к конкретному UserControl. Единственный способ, давший результат - в главной VM делаю статичное свойство, которое ссылается на саму себя (this) и в CodeBehind UserControl делаю привязку DataContext на имеющийся список ViewModel (выбираю тот, который должен быть у данной UC)

Comment: @АртемийСоболев: Здесь я не понимаю без кода, что именно вам нужно. Поскольку это отдельная от данного вопроса вещь, имеет смысл задать её отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @VladD почему `TabControl` именно в `Header` подставляет один из шаблонов, который объявлен у него в ресурсах?

Comment: @sp7: Он подставляет везде, где ему нужно отобразить VM-объект, и непонятно, как именно. Для TabControl таких мест два: Header и содержимое таба. Но для содержимого я специально даю другой шаблон, так что остаётся лишь Header. (А если бы не дал, в содержимом таба отображалось бы то же самое.)

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: как передать в ViewModel каждого UserConrtol идентификатор выбранного объекта, и общие команды (как "Сохранить", "Стереть")?

В очень упрощенном виде, я бы делал так:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <ref:ItemControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <ref:SecondItemControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>

public partial class ItemControl : UserControl
{
    public ItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object Sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs Args)
    {
        if (Args.NewValue is Item)
        {
            DataContext = new ItemViewModel(Args.NewValue as Item);
        }
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(Item Context)
    {
    }
}

public class Item
{
}
```