# Как сделать универсальный метод присвоения значений?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Хочу унифицировать функцию присвоения, чтобы не делать ее на каждый тип переменных, использовать шаблон. Но почему-то возникает ошибка. Как их использовать? Никогда не пробовал, и не знаю с какой стороны к ним подойти (хотя в чужом коде достаточно часто вижу такое применение)

Необходимо сделать функцию присвоения одному объекту другой объект, с различными проверками.

Пытался сделать так:

```
public void Set<T>(ref T Property, T Value)
    {
        if (Property != Value && Value != null)
        {
            Property = Value;
        }
    }
```

Но возникает ошибка при сравнении объектов `Property != Value`. Как можно провести сравнение неопределенных типов?

Comment: Попробуйте `!Equals(Property, Value)`

Comment: Или так `!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(property, value)`.

Comment: И почитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982645/how-to-solve-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t - тут есть ответы почему так сделано.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Так и есть, работает.

Comment: @monk оформите ответом, закрою вопрос

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628276/10105

Comment: @VladD, да, дубликат

Comment: @pincher1519: Тогда бахну.